It is possible to set up ray cluster on top of p2p networks?
i am learning libp2p and ray.
just wonder whether it is possible to get the IPs (reachable IPs among these nodes) of some nodes in p2p networks and then set up ray cluster on these nodes? here, we do not consider the join/leave of these nodes. i am just curious whether it is easy to do this. among these nodes (setup by libp2p), one node is picked up as head, other nodes are worker nodes.
Thanks
any comments/suggestions are welcomed.
